# How do i get a send button to only submit and write to its own inputField?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner and I'm now stuck trying to figure out two things for the below code:

1. How do I code so that each of the send buttons only connects to its own input field?
2. How do I code so that each new text input overwrites the previous?

My code:

```
<h1>Data input</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="inputField1" name="lastName" required>
<input type="button" value="Send" id="myButton1">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" id="inputField2" name="firstName" required>
<input type="button" value="Send" id="myButton2">
<br>
<br>
<p id="lastName">Last name</p>
<p id="firstName">First name</p>
<script>
    var b1=document.getElementById("myButton1")
    b1.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    var b2=document.getElementById("myButton2")
    b2.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    
    function handleClick(){
        
        var i=document.getElementById("inputField1");
        var iValue=i.value;
    
        var d=document.getElementById("lastName");
        
        var oldText=d.innerText;
        var newText=oldText+"\n"+iValue;
        d.innerText=newText;
        
        
        var k=document.getElementById("inputField2");
        var kValue=k.value;
        
        var f=document.getElementById("firstName");
        
        var oldText=f.innerText;
        var newText=oldText+"\n"+kValue;
        f.innerText=newText;
                
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that sends a `1` or a `2` to the `handleClick` function as a parameter depending on which button you click. It then gets the value of the input that matches the number, checks to make see if it is empty, and outputs the name to the correct paragraph if it isn't and an error message if it is. Let me know if you have any problems with it.

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById("myButton1");
b1.addEventListener("click", () => handleClick("1"));
var b2 = document.getElementById("myButton2");
b2.addEventListener("click", () => handleClick("2"));

function handleClick(iNum){
  
  var i = document.getElementById("inputField" + iNum);
  var iValue = i.value;
  var d = document.getElementById("name" + iNum);
  if (iValue != "") {
    var pText = (iNum == "1" ? "Last" : "First");
    var newText = pText + " name: " + iValue;
    d.textContent = newText;
  } else {
    d.textContent = "Please enter a name!";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Data input</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="inputField1" name="lastName" required>
<input type="button" value="Send" id="myButton1">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" id="inputField2" name="firstName" required>
<input type="button" value="Send" id="myButton2">
<br>
<br>
<p id="name1"></p>
<p id="name2"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure what's going on here, but usually you have to access the input field via the event: event.target.value (just put event as a parameter)

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question